# Get the two instances with most number of items in common

Tags: python

I'm trying to analyze a database of trucks and the items they carry to find out **which two trucks are the most similar to one another (trucks which share the most number of items)**. I have a csv similar to this:

```
truck_id | item_id
13       | 85394 *
16       | 294 *
13       | 294 *
89       | 3115
89       | 85394
13       | 294
16       | 85394 *
13       | 3115
```

In the above example, `16` and `13` are the most similar trucks, as they both have the `294` and `85394` items.

The entire code is too long so I'll offer pseudo code for what I'm doing:

```
truck_items = {}

#1
loop over the csv:
    add to truck_items a truck_id and an ARRAY with the items each truck has

#2
go over each truck in the truck_items dictionary, and compare their array to all other arrays
to get the count of similar items

#3
create a 'most_similar' key in the dictionary.

#4
check in most_similar what are the two trucks with most similarity.
```

So I would end up with something like this:

```
{
  13: [16, 2] // truck_1_id: [truck_2_id, number_similar_items]
  89: ...
}
```

I understand this is not the most efficient way as I'm going ever the lists too many times and that shouldn't be done. Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` to gather all records for a given truck.  For each group, make a set of part numbers.  Make a new data frame of that data:

```
truck_id | items
13       | {85394, 294, 3115}
16       | {294, 85394}
89       | {3115, 85394}
```

Now you need to make a full cross-product of this DF with itself; filter to remove self-reference and duplicates (13-16 and 16-13, for example).  If you make the product with
`truck_id_left < truck_id_right` (I'll leave the implementation syntax to you, dependent on the package you use), you'll get only the unique pairs.

On that series of truck pairs, simply take the set intersection of their items:

```
trucks | items
(13, 16)       | {85394, 294}
(13, 89)       | {3115}
(16, 89)       | {85394}
```

Then find the row with the `max` value on that intersection.

Can you handle each of those steps?  They're all contained in PANDAS tutorials.

Comment: If OP does not use pandas or does not want to use pandas for a trivial (?) task, they can achieve the same with `defaultdict(set)` (so only with built-in tools: `collections.defaultdict` and `itertools.product`), and probably less lines of code (or even at the database query level)

Comment: Ummm ... that's `len`, as it is with any sequence type.

Answer (score 2):

Non-pandas solution, facilitating built-in tools such as `collections.defaultdict` (optional) and `itertools.product` (also optional, but will help you push some calculations/loops down to the C level which will be beneficial if the data set is large enough).

I think the logic itself is self-explanatory.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product

trucks = [
    (13, 294),
    (13, 294),
    (13, 3115),
    (13, 85394),
    (16, 294),
    (16, 85394),
    (89, 3115),
    (89, 85394),
]

d = defaultdict(set)
for truck, load in trucks:
    d[truck].add(load)


li = [({'truck': k1, 'items': v1},
       {'truck': k2, 'items': v2})
       for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in product(d.items(), repeat=2)
       if k1 != k2]

truck_1_data, truck_2_data = max(li, key=lambda e: len(e[0]['items'] & e[1]['items']))
print(truck_1_data['truck'], truck_2_data['truck'])
```

outputs

```
13 16
```

Arguably a more readable version:

```
...

li = [{k1: v1,
       k2: v2}
      for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in product(d.items(), repeat=2)
      if k1 != k2]

def dict_values_intersection_len(d):
    values = list(d.values())
    return len(values[0] & values[1])


truck_1, truck_2 = max(li, key=dict_values_intersection_len)
print(truck_1, truck_2)
```

which also outputs

```
13 16
```

Comment: how could I also get the number of items that are present in both?

Comment: @uber In the first approach I showed, if you print `truck_1_data['items']` you will get the items. Same goes for `truck_2_data['items']`

Comment: @uber Using `&` on 2 sets returns their intersection

Comment: @uber Of course! good catch. I'll fix the answer

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution that seems like it might work:

I'm using pandas as my main data container, just makes stuff like this easier.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
```

Here I'm creating a similar dataset

```
#creating toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'truck_id':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3],'item_id':[1,7,1,7,5,2,2]})
```

that looks like this

```
   item_id  truck_id
0        1         1
1        7         1
2        1         2
3        7         2
4        5         2
5        2         3
6        2         3
```

I'm reformatting it to have a list of items for each truck

```
#making it so each row is a truck, and the value is a list of items
df = df.groupby('truck_id')['item_id'].apply(list)
```

which looks like this:

```
truck_id
1       [1, 7]
2    [1, 7, 5]
3       [2, 2]
```

now I'm creating a function that, given a df that looks like the previous one, counts the number of similar items on 2 trucks.

```
def get_num_similar(df, id0, id1):
    #drops duplicates from each truck, so there's only one of each item in each truck
    #combining those lists together, so it's a list of items in both trucks
    comp = [*list(set(df.loc[id0])), *list(set(df.loc[id1]))]

    #getting how many items of each exist (should be 1 or 2)
    quants = dict(Counter(comp))

    #getting how many similar items are carried
    num_similar = len([quant for quant in quants.values() if quant > 1])

    return num_similar
```

running this:

```
print(get_num_similar(df, 1, 2))
```

results in an output of `2`, which is accurate. Now just iterate over all groups of trucks you want to analyze, and you can calculate which trucks have the most shared things.

Comment: Note, this probably isn't perfect, you can probably do similarity counting in pandas directly, which would be way faster. That said, I would guess this solution is probably fine given the pace of the transportation sector.

Comment: Anyway, this does not answer the question. You provided OP with a function that accepts `id0` and `id1` as arguments, where OP asked how to find these `id0` and `id1`

Comment: Makes sense that you're so highly rated. Didn't realize it was a competition, you should probably take a break. Also, it does work, I ran it; I just said it could probably be improved. "might work" is incredibly passive aggressive and not necessary. This is a completely voluntary, community based sight; negative comments like that have no place. Please remove it, and I'll remove this.

Comment: Also, this goes without saying by "might work" I meant "might work for the op's use case"

Comment: SO is a Q&A site. The whole point of posting an answer is that it *is* working (not *might work*) for OP's specific use-case. I never wrote that this answer is *bad* or anything about a "competition", just questioned your writing *"seems like it might work"*. If it works, why even mention that it "might" work?

Comment: The entire project was offered in pseudo code, which means I have no way of guaranteeing that it will work in the op's use case, and the question is in a somewhat conversational tone, so is my reposne. Also, that's not the whole point of stack overflow. The point of stack overflow is to be a repository for high quality answers that are easily referenceable and understandable. While this is a product of Q&A, Q&A is not the end all be all of stack overflow. I'm sorry if I was heated, but terse, elitest comments are a pervasive issue on this sight, and the "might work" comment read as such.